# Trouble getting wordpress site up from files

Tags: php, wordpress

Someone made a wordpress site for my boss, and I received a zip with all the files which contains a wp-admin, wp-content and wp-includes folder and other files in the root. My boss wants me to use godaddy to setup the site. 
On godaddy they only have 2 ways to setup a site either new or to migrate and for migrate it seems you need to have a site already up and pass it to their servers.

So I figured I would create a new site and then replace it. So I created a new site via godaddy and then I skipped the quick setup, I FTP to my godaddy server and I saw that I had a html folder with a wp-admin, wp-content and wp-includes so I tried to delete and upload mine but I didn't havce permission to delete some files also trying to copy on top I got permission denials. So what I did was rename the html folder to html1 and create a new html folder and upload all the files I received into it.

But I still cant get my site up, if I tried to go direct to the site it didnt work and so I tried running the install.php in the wp-admin as I read in a readme but then I had a cant find theme error and when I put in a theme now I get that theme and I dont get the site I am trying to run.

I have looked online but all I see is guides on creating a WP site from new, I cant seem to find how to get a site working from having the files much less a guide that shows how to do it on godaddy.com

These are the contents of the only .sql file I have

```
/*
Navicat MySQL Data Transfer

Source Server         : example.com
Source Server Version : 50634
Source Host           : mysql.example.com:3306
Source Database       : example

Target Server Type    : MYSQL
Target Server Version : 50634
File Encoding         : 65001

Date: 2018-08-27 20:09:50
*/

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for example
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`;
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `symbol` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `percent_change_1h` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of example
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `example` VALUES ('1', 'BTC', '4718.20', '1504212813', '2017-08-31 16:54:01', null);
INSERT INTO `example` VALUES ('2', 'BTC', '4387.00', '1506804865', '2017-09-30 16:56:50', null);
INSERT INTO `example` VALUES ('3', 'BTC', '6458.30', '1509483265', '2017-10-31 16:58:15', null);
INSERT INTO `example` VALUES ('4', 'BTC', '9907.00', '1512075265', '2017-11-30 17:00:35', null);
INSERT INTO `example` VALUES ('5', 'BTC', '13800.00', '1514753665', '2017-12-31 17:01:50', null);
INSERT INTO `example` VALUES ('6', 'BTC', '10284.00', '1517432065', '2018-01-31 17:03:22', null);
INSERT INTO `example` VALUES ('7', 'BTC', '10315.00', '1519851265', '2018-02-28 17:04:22', null);
```

There were more INSERT statements I cut off

Comment: Ideally, you should have received the database file (.sql) as well. If you have not received that .sql file, you won't be able to configure the website. In that case, ask the developer to provide you with the database dump in .sql format.

Comment: I do have a .sql file in another folder in the root dir which contains Source Server and target server info commented out and also Table structure and Records, is that it??? what do i do with this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have access to control panel of your hosting account. (I am stating below sequence of steps as if this is the first attempt.)

- Hope you know the previous URL in the database. You need to change that before you can use that database. If you don't know the previous URL, you find it as follows:

  - Open .sql file in any text editor
  - Search for `siteurl`
  - Just next to that will be an URL. That is the one you need to note.
- Make a copy of that .sql file and open the copy in any text editor.
- Using "Search & Replace" tool of search editor, search the previously noted URL and change it with your website's URL. E.g. if the previous URL is "http://somewebsite.com" and your target website's URL is, "http://newwebsite.com", then change all occurrences of "http://somewebsite.com" to "http://newwebsite.com".
- In your new hosting environment, create a new (blank) database with its corresponding user and password. Keep note of those details as they will be required later. i.e. *Database name, Database username, Database user's password*.
- From the WordPress files, open `wp-config.php` file in any text editor and change the database name, database username & database user password. Use the values you have noted while you created the new database and its user in Cpanel.
- Access your new database via phpMyAdmin. Find the database import option and import the updated .sql file into your database.
- If your's is Linux hosting, then there should be a folder "publc_html". Upload all the WordPress related files to that folder (via FTP).

That's all. If your domain name is already pointing to the new hosting environment, you should be able to browse your website normally.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I dont know if the .sql file I have is the right one, I posted the contents above, there is no siteurl variable the only website it has says Source Server and Source Host, but it doesnt seem to be what you are refferring to or is it?

Comment: This seems to be the dump of just one of the tables in the database. I am afraid, the  .sql file you have is not a valid database backup which you can use to host the website. If possible contact the developer and get the complete dump of the database.

Comment: Ok thank you for the guidance, wasnt sure what I was missing, will try to get it and follow the steps above and see if I can get it to work.